# show message before creating PHP session and redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication

I am trying to show a success message before creating a PHP session and redirecting to another page. The problem is that if I use the `sleep()` function, once I submit the form it just sleeps for 3 seconds and then redirects the same to the next page without showing the message. Here is the bit of code where I am having this trouble:

```
if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Foi registado com sucesso!</div>';
    sleep(3);
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user_email;
    header("Location: areacliente.php");
}
}else{
    $erro .="O registo falhou!";
}
```

Comment: You may want to rethink this. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php): Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Comment: I suggest completely changing your approach. I might glance down to grab my drink and not have time to read it. What if I misread and want to re-read? Shoving text at someone but with a timeout is really bad UX. Instead of auto redirect, why not a button or link to the next page, then the user can click when ready. Or show the message on the next page. Hard to give design approach ideas without knowing the full story but you're trying to fix something that will always be user un-friendly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be done using JavaScript. Also as noted by the commenters, you may want to either have a button or write the message on the next page. It looks like the message isn't critical, so auto-disappearing is probably not a problem:

**Option 1 - JavaScript Redirect:**

Use essentially the same script you have now, but use javascript to redirect.

```
if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)):
    # Assign before message
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user_email ?>
    <!-- write message -->
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Foi registado com sucesso!</div>
    <!-- create timeout -->
    <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = 'areacliente.php';
    }, 3000);
    </script>
<?php else:
    $erro .="O registo falhou!";
endif;
```

---

**Option 2 - Message to Next:**

Assign the session and just redirect to the next page, then show the message on that page and auto-hide it on countdown (or not).

**/whatever_file_this_is.php**

```
# Just set this as default false
$_SESSION['success'] = false;
if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)){
    # Set this to true for the next page
    $_SESSION['success'] = true;
    # Set the email as you have it
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user_email;
    # Redirect
    header("Location: areacliente.php");
    # Stop so rest of the script doesn't run
    exit;
}
else {
    $erro .="O registo falhou!";
}
```

**/areacliente.php**

```
<?php
# Check if the session success is true
if(!empty($_SESSION['success'])):
    # Remove it since it's being used now
    unset($_SESSION['success']); ?>
    <!-- Add an id to this div -->
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success-msg">Foi registado com sucesso!</div>
    <!-- count down and hide the message after 3 sections -->
    <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('success-msg').style.display = 'none';
    },3000);
    </script>
<?php endif ?>
```